# 'python' not working in shell and python -V also shows error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
$ python

bash: /usr/local/bin/python2.7: No such file or directory
```

When I type python in terminal I get the above error. Although both python2 and python3 are working fine.

```
panda123@panda123:~$ python2
Python 2.7.12 (default, Jul 21 2020, 15:19:50) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 

panda123@panda123:~$ python3
Python 3.7.8 (default, Jun 29 2020, 05:46:05) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

When I run this command

```
panda123@panda123:~$ ls -l /usr/bin/python*
```

I get the following output:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      18 Jul 27 19:14 /usr/bin/python -> /usr/bin/python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Nov 24  2017 /usr/bin/python2 -> python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3644504 Jul 21 22:41 /usr/bin/python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      31 Jul 21 22:41 /usr/bin/python2.7-config -> i386-linux-gnu-python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Nov 24  2017 /usr/bin/python2-config -> python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      25 Jul 26 11:06 /usr/bin/python3 -> /etc/alternatives/python3
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4776276 Jul 20 01:47 /usr/bin/python3.5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      31 Jul 20 01:47 /usr/bin/python3.5-config -> i386-linux-gnu-python3.5-config
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4776276 Jul 20 01:47 /usr/bin/python3.5m
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      32 Jul 20 01:47 /usr/bin/python3.5m-config -> i386-linux-gnu-python3.5m-config
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4865996 Jun 29 13:02 /usr/bin/python3.6
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4865996 Jun 29 13:02 /usr/bin/python3.6m
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 5222104 Jun 29 12:53 /usr/bin/python3.7
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 5222104 Jun 29 12:53 /usr/bin/python3.7m
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Mar 23  2016 /usr/bin/python3-config -> python3.5-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      10 May  3 19:15 /usr/bin/python3m -> python3.5m
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      17 Mar 23  2016 /usr/bin/python3m-config -> python3.5m-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Nov 24  2017 /usr/bin/python-config -> python2.7-config
```

This is the output I get when I type `which python`

```
panda123@panda123:~$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

When I type python -V I get the following output.

```
panda123@panda123:~$ python -V
bash: /usr/local/bin/python2.7: No such file or directory
```

This is the output of  `gedit ~/.bashrc`

```
# enable bash completion in interactive shells
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi

alias usage='du -sk * | sort -n | perl -ne '\''($s,$f)=split(m{\t});for (qw(K M G)) {if($s<1024) {printf("%.1f",$s);print "$_\t$f"; last};$s=$s/1024}'\'
alias ls="ls --color"
```

I don't know what to do. I don't know much of the technicalities. Please help. I have already spent more than 5 hrs on this, looked every resource on Internet.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the access, you could try to remove and relink `python`

```
$ sudo rm /usr/bin/python
$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
OR
$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/python
```

Also, do you get the same response when you use the full path?

```
$ /usr/bin/python
```